# Programmatically finding MS-Access 2007 Table 'Field index' to be present? TField.IsIndexedField not working

Tags: delphi, ms-access-2007, ado, delphi-2007

My table Customers has a field UserID which is indexed.

[image]

Now when I am dropping this Field from delphi, I am getting EOleExecption as its a indexed field.
I tried with following code:

```
ObjCustomers := TADOTable.Create(nil);    
ObjCustomers.Connection := Connection;        
ObjCustomers.TableName := 'Customers';
ObjCustomers.Open;

if (ObjCustomers.FindField('UserID').IsIndexField) then
begin      
  ExecuteSQLStatements(['DROP INDEX UserID ON Customers']);    
end;
```

But this Tfield.IsIndexField is coming up False for this case.
**Further I dont wanna do something like this:**

```
try      
  ExecuteSQLStatements(['DROP INDEX UserID ON Customers']);    
except 
  on E: exception do    
end;
```

Is there any way so that I can check whether the field is Indexed, before executing SQL query?

Thankx in advance!

Comment: I'm quite sure [`this`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Obtaining_Information_About_Indexes) might help you ;)

Comment: The TADOconnection has a OpenSchema method which you may use to find indexed fields

Comment: @TLama, very nice. `TADODataSet` is actually implementing `GetIndexNames` (internally using `OpenSchema(siIndexes...`. I never knew of such method till today and always used `OpenSchema` directlly :) You should post it as an answer.

Comment: @kobik, feel free to include it into yours ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetIsIndexField` is not implemented by `TADODataSet`, and the result will be `False`.

Use `TADOConnection.OpenSchema` to retrieves table indexes:

```
var DataSet: TADODataSet;

DataSet := TADODataSet.Create(nil);
try
  Connection.OpenSchema(siIndexes, VarArrayOf([Unassigned, Unassigned, Unassigned, Unassigned, 'Customers']), EmptyParam, DataSet);
  while not DataSet.Eof do begin
    ShowMessage(DataSet.FieldByName('INDEX_NAME').AsString);
    DataSet.Next;
  end;
finally
  DataSet.Free;
end;
```

---

To make this answer complete: 
As suggested by [TLama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/960757/tlama) you can use the `TADODataSet` method [`GetIndexNames`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Obtaining_Information_About_Indexes).
`ADO` is internally using `Command.ActiveConnection.OpenSchema(adSchemaIndexes...`

```
function IsIndexField(DataSet: TADODataSet; FieldName: string): Boolean;
var
  SL: TStringList;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    DataSet.GetIndexNames(SL);
    Result := SL.IndexOf(FieldName) <> -1;
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ObjCustomers: TADOTable;
begin
  ObjCustomers := TADOTable.Create(nil);
  ObjCustomers.Connection := Connection;
  ObjCustomers.TableName := 'Customers';

  if IsIndexField(TADODataSet(ObjCustomers), 'UserID') then
  begin
    Showmessage('Index');
    Connection.Execute('DROP INDEX UserID ON Customers');
  end
  else
    Showmessage('Not Index');

  // ObjCustomers.Open;
  ObjCustomers.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks guys, but its not working out :(. With these solns I am getting only 1 Indexed field, ID which is the Primary_Key defined. For this field UserID, I somehow wrongly put Indexed-Yes manually at design time. Does that makes it a indexed field? If yes, then I am not getting this with the code u mentioned. Further GetIndexNames returns nothing, ItemCount = 0. Well I m still trying, but for such a table where u make 1 field like i mentioned' in Access, and if this code works, then i wonder what I m doing wrong! Many Thanks though!

Comment: please define "I somehow wrongly put Indexed-Yes manually at design time".

Comment: :) It means I never meant to use this field as indexed. kind of temporary field, and I added it manually and ideally it should be set to Indexed = no from access design view. Now I wanna drop this field, and I am getting the OLE Exception which says cannot drop Indexed field.

Comment: consider the fact that you see only 1 Indexed field ID, because you dropped the Index in the first time. see my edit. works as expected for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
VAR
 AdoTbl:TAdoDataset;
BEGIN
  AdoTbl:=TAdoDataset.Create(Self); // use TAdoDataset 
  AdoTbl.Connection  :=MyAdoConnection;
  AdoTbl.CommandType:=cmdTable; //Importent !!
  AdoTbl.CommandText:='Refx_Ceramics_Hist_PreHist'; //Tablename 

  AdoTbl.GetIndexNames(ListBox1.Items);
END;
```

This works for me  on DelphiXE2